# Question related to find/replace using propertyregex

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

In my ant build file, I have a property 'Version' that contains the version. Ex. **2.5.17.230**

Now, I am using `propertyregex` of ant-contrib to replace all '.' (dot) characters with an underscore. I have written the statement as follows:

`<propertyregex property="Version" input="${Version}" regexp="." replace="_" global="true" />`

However, it does not work. I have even tried these in vain:
`regexp="\."` and `regexp="[.]"`

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The `PropertyRegex` [documentation](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) states that unless the `override` attribute is set to `true`, the task will not overwrite the property value if it's already set. And since you're trying to overwrite the `Version` property, your example will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I was passing the same variable as input. I used another variable 'Version2' to get the result from propertyregex. Here is what it should have been:

`<propertyregex property="Version2" input="${Version}" regexp="\." replace="_" global="true" />`

Cheers!